# .NET Memory leak in Windows Service diagnosing using WinDbg

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, windbg

### The problem:

Over the course of a few days, the memory will continue to increase in memory size until it has no memory left with it been 32bit application it only can allocate 3.5GB. This program generates reports based from various ERPs, Webservices, FTP which sends it out in various formats CSV, SMS and so on.

### Application:

I'm using the following main packages installed:

- Hangfire v1.7.10
- Hangfire SqlSever v1.7.10
- SimpleImpersonation v3.0
- CsvHelper v15.0.4
- Dapper v2.0.35
- esendex-dotnet-sdk v3.8
- FastMember v1.5
- FluentFTP v23.3.1
- Microsoft.Owin v4.1
- Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.3
- Serilog v2.9
- Serilog.Sinks.Seq v4.0
- Interop.SageDataObject250 v25 (x86 only)

It's Windows Service using .NET Framework v4.7.2 compiled for x86 due to Sage reference.

### The steps I've tried to diagnose the problem:

I've run Task Manager in x86 and generated a DMP using **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe**

I've copied the DMP onto my development PC and ran WinDbg in x86 mode using -debugArch x86 command

I've run the command `.loadby sos clr` then `!address -summary` which gives the following results:

```
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Heap                                  26731          c4ece000 (   3.077 GB)  84.59%   76.93%
<unknown>                               962          17b0b000 ( 379.043 MB)  10.18%    9.25%
Free                                    266          1733e000 ( 371.242 MB)            9.06%
Image                                   958           8b55000 ( 139.332 MB)   3.74%    3.40%
Stack                                   171           36c0000 (  54.750 MB)   1.47%    1.34%
TEB                                      57             7b000 ( 492.000 kB)   0.01%    0.01%
Other                                     8             46000 ( 280.000 kB)   0.01%    0.01%
PEB                                       1              3000 (  12.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                           27660          dd421000 (   3.457 GB)  95.04%   86.43%
MEM_IMAGE                              1186           93e7000 ( 147.902 MB)   3.97%    3.61%
MEM_MAPPED                               42           24aa000 (  36.664 MB)   0.98%    0.90%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_COMMIT                            26966          d4334000 (   3.316 GB)  91.15%   82.89%
MEM_FREE                                266          1733e000 ( 371.242 MB)            9.06%
MEM_RESERVE                            1922          1497e000 ( 329.492 MB)   8.85%    8.04%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                        14073          c60df000 (   3.095 GB)  85.08%   77.37%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       108           6730000 ( 103.188 MB)   2.77%    2.52%
PAGE_READONLY                           365           4181000 (  65.504 MB)   1.76%    1.60%
PAGE_NOACCESS                         11990           2ed6000 (  46.836 MB)   1.26%    1.14%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                          270            791000 (   7.566 MB)   0.20%    0.18%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   46            220000 (   2.125 MB)   0.06%    0.05%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD               114            11d000 (   1.113 MB)   0.03%    0.03%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Heap                                        d69a7000            2b8000 (   2.719 MB)
<unknown>                                   f7f62000           1a88000 (  26.531 MB)
Free                                        fb230000           3920000 (  57.125 MB)
Image                                       70630000            f55000 (  15.332 MB)
Stack                                        1c60000             fc000 (1008.000 kB)
TEB                                           e68000              3000 (  12.000 kB)
Other                                       fecb0000             23000 ( 140.000 kB)
PEB                                           f53000              3000 (  12.000 kB)
```

I can see 3GB in the heap, so then I've ran `!eeheap -gc`

```
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0xf161e75c
generation 1 starts at 0xf1612484
generation 2 starts at 0x01e11000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
01e10000  01e11000  02e0ff68  0xffef68(16772968)
2ac00000  2ac01000  2bbfff58  0xffef58(16772952)
e1b70000  e1b71000  e2b6fe3c  0xffee3c(16772668)
dbba0000  dbba1000  dcba0000  0xfff000(16773120)
95e60000  95e61000  96e5ff30  0xffef30(16772912)
c6e40000  c6e41000  c7e3ff70  0xffef70(16772976)
dcba0000  dcba1000  ddb9ff54  0xffef54(16772948)
ddba0000  ddba1000  deb9fccc  0xffeccc(16772300)
dfb70000  dfb71000  e0b6ff2c  0xffef2c(16772908)
e3b40000  e3b41000  e4b3ffac  0xffefac(16773036)
e4b40000  e4b41000  e5b3fec0  0xffeec0(16772800)
f07e0000  f07e1000  f17c17bc  0xfe07bc(16648124)
Large object heap starts at 0x02e11000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
02e10000  02e11000  030f2dd8  0x2e1dd8(3022296)
e0b70000  e0b71000  e1af14c0  0xf804c0(16254144)
f3780000  f3781000  f42012a0  0xa802a0(11010720)
Total Size:              Size: 0xdcb7248 (231436872) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:    Size: 0xdcb7248 (231436872) bytes.
```

231436872 B = 231.436872 MB
So, where is the rest of the memory?

`!heap -s`

```
************************************************************************************************************************
                                              NT HEAP STATS BELOW
************************************************************************************************************************
LFH Key                   : 0x71f51955
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01440000 00000002 3221644 3049200 3221588  31845  2238  1075    0     83   LFH
01360000 00001002    1136     88   1080     20     9     2    0      0   LFH
01930000 00001002    1136    132   1080     10    11     2    0      0   LFH
018c0000 00001002    1136    216   1080      4    50     2    0      0   LFH
01e00000 00041002      60      4     60      2     1     1    0      0      
04420000 00041002     116     28     60      3     2     1    0      0   LFH
091c0000 00001002      60     12     60      4     2     1    0      0      
0a8b0000 00001002    1136    212   1080     73    10     2    0      0   LFH
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`!dumpheap -stat`

```
7030f850      238        74436 System.Char[]
7030bff0     1279        86972 System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo
01df8d24      218       131672 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Single, mscorlib],[OfficeOpenXml.FontSizeInfo, EPPlus]][]
703109ac     1179       134016 System.Int32[]
7030f378     1416       156412 System.Object[]
7030b680     3479       208740 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
6b01c4c8        2       524312 System.Data.DataRow[]
6b01cc24      104      2594016 System.Data.RBTree`1+Node[[System.Data.DataRow, System.Data]][]
70312158     3995      2676025 System.Byte[]
6b01bd4c    80417      5468356 System.Data.DataRow
0145b368      183      6617958      Free
7030f964      406     24582180 System.String[]
7030f0d4  3392330    183245330 System.String
```

So .NET heap doesn't have much memory allocated. I've trimmed it down since the list was massive but these were from bottom the biggest memory allocated.

I'm not overly familiar with WinDbg but I'm assuming it's a native heap memory leak?

So, the only thing I could think of which may use native heaps and so on is the SimpleImpersonation and Sage due to it using COM objects?

If anyone has any advise or push me in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

I've reviewed over my code to make sure anything which has IDisposable uses an using statement.

Comment: From `!address`, the line `Heap 3.077 GB` already tells you that most of the memory used is native memory. Since WinDbg doesn't know about .NET, these are not .NET heaps, they are heaps from the Microsoft Heap Manager, which is used by C++.

Comment: .NET uses its own heap management due to garbage collection. Thus it's based on the virtual memory manager inestead of the heap manager. You find .NET in the `<unknown>` line of `!address`. However, there may be a few .NET objects holding references to native objects, so that the cause for the native memory leak is on the .NET side. In case of COM, there are RCWs managing the references. Make sure you release the COM objects properly. Maybe you need to introduce more IDisposable.

Comment: 2 things I'd try to do in such situation. 1) check the hypothesis of unmanaged because of managed leak - take dump when vm size is 1 gb, and what it's 3. Investigate the contents of managed heap and try to find correlations between allocation size and some specific instances count (like FileSystemWatcher, for example, small managed instance with large unmanaged buffer) . 2) Use DebugDiag and Native memory and handle leak analysis to find most allocating modules.

Comment: Thanks for help guys. I did think it was native memory but wasn't certain. That's a good idea, I'll try to find the module which is using all the memory up and I'll check over DebugDiag too. Thanks.

Comment: Try debugging using UMDH

Comment: Thanks @kvr for the recommendation. I'll check it out in future. I did manage to find the route cause of the problem was Sage, only due to isolating part by part.